# How to read and append elements in a one-dimension ndarray?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

So, I have an ndarray with ***shape*** (0,) and I'm trying to access its elements. Should I use ***append*** to fill it in or something else? How can I read its contents?

Comment: What have you did so far? Add the code you wrote and didn't worked or add the error you faced during programming to your question.

Comment: @EbraHim I tried ***print a[0]*** (a is the array) but it obviously gives ***Evaluation: index out of bounds - Error***

Answer (score 0):

If the shape of your array is `(0, )` it has no elements (therefore there’s obviously none to access).

However, if you wish to **append** an element to the end of your array, you may use [`np.append`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.ndarray(0)
array([], dtype=float64)
>>> arr = np.append(arr, 17)
array([ 17.])
```

and so on…